# Image isnt resizing for ipad screen/iphone mode

Tags: html, css, image, resize, media-queries

can anyone find the solution to my problem? I've beed tweaking my CSS sheets and it doesnt seem like its changing anything. I'm using the same rules for the "4sites" image as to my "About" img.

Heres a link to the site, you can see all of my css sheets from there too. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/146014194/483F_ss14/Pro01/hwk/pro01_content_structure_presentation_B02_responsive_4sites_FINAL.html

I know you can create everything in just one CSS sheet, but my professor asked us to make it like the way it is..

I added a div tag around the img thinking that I could control it better.. But it doesnt seem like its the case!

Mucho Thanks!

Comment: hi...please post the relevant HTML/CSS...link based question dont serve purpose to future visitors!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to keep the height of image as 100%. If this is a responsive design then, the width has to be 100% and height to be kept as auto

**CSS:**

```
#Mybio #Mepic img {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
```

Now the question is, the image is taking the whole width of the screen, well, that's normal. You have to restrict the parent **div(id** as **#Mepic)** and handle it with media queries for different screen sizes. Also I saw float issues on you're site. Use **Clear:both** to get rid of them.